# Looping using Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is a dataset

[image]
the target is to select song id with atleast 1 composer and 1 publisher on at least one line. For example songid 4 has 2 lines with 2 different composer but no publisher and song id 1 has no composer. The goal is reject such excel sheets using Python(pandas) Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import smtplib
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

df_header = pd.read_csv('New York Yankees Twins at Yankees-FNG-042318.csv',header=None,skiprows=1)
cuesheetprepareremail = df_header.iloc[0,7]
print(cuesheetprepareremail)


df = pd.read_csv('New York Yankees Twins at Yankees-FNG-042318.csv',
                 names=['CUE','SONG TITLE','USAGE','RUNNING TIME','COMPOSER','COMPOSER PRO','COMPOSER % SHARE','PUBLISHER',' PUBLISHER PRO','PUBLISHER % SHARE' ,'TRACK ID','LIBRARY','ARTIST','START TIME'
],skiprows=7)

#select all rows with same cue number
columns = ['CUE','COMPOSER','PUBLISHER']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=columns)

df1 = df1.replace('', np.NaN)
gp = df1.groupby('CUE').count()
fileToSend = 'New York Yankees Twins at Yankees-FNG-042318.csv'
emailfrom = ''
emailto = 'xyz@abc.com'
username= ''
password = ''

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Enco error testing'

msg['From'] = emailfrom
msg['To'] = emailto
msg.preamble = 'Enco error testing'

if gp[(gp['COMPOSER'] == 0) | (gp['PUBLISHER'] == 0)] :

    # Send the email via our own SMTP server.
    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Comment: You should format your question to include your dataset as code.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `DataFrame` `df`

```
   Song_Id        SONG TITLE *USAGE RUNNING COMPOSER(s)  COMPOSE PUBLISHER(s)
0        1    Testing Moment    BGI                        ASCAP        audio
1        2  Rented Dreams-JP    BGI              Andrew  ABRAMUS         Nova
2        2                                         Paul      UBC             
3        2                                        Molly      UBC             
4        3     Gridiron Rock    BGI               Brian    ASCAP       Client
5        3                                       Daniel    ASCAP             
6        4          Rock Run    BGI             Sharron    ASCAP             
7        4                                   Kyle Towns    ASCAP
```

You should fill the empty strings with `np.NaN` and then you can use `groupby` + `count`, and apply your logic to the grouped object.

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.NaN)
gp = df.groupby('Song_Id').count()

gp[(gp['COMPOSER(s)'] > 0) & (gp['PUBLISHER(s)'] > 0)]
#         *USAGE  COMPOSE  COMPOSER(s)  PUBLISHER(s)  RUNNING  SONG TITLE
#Song_Id                                                                 
#2             1        3            3             1        0           1
#3             1        2            2             1        0           1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried to edit my code using your suggestion but it is throwing an error. Any suggestions would help.